# Nuxt Build on heroku does not work but runs locally

Tags: node.js, vue.js, heroku, nuxt.js

i have a nuxt application which i need to deploy on heroku. locally everything works fine. when i install dependencies (locally) there are a lot of unmet dependencies but like i said it works perfectly even when i run build scripts. however when i push to heroku it says build succeded but the app does not work. then i tried building the app on heroku manually by using bash commands on heroku. when i run build script it fails to build with this error :

```
   │   ✖ Nuxt Fatal Error                                   │
       Error: Cannot find module '@nuxt/typescript-build'   │
   │   Require stack:                                       │
   │   - /app/node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js          │
   │   - /app/node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli-index.js      │
   │   - /app/node_modules/@nuxt/cli/dist/cli.js            │
   │   - /app/node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js
```

when i checked *'@nuxt/typescript-build'* in **package.json** file it is mentionned under **devDependencies** (i ran yarn install before building app)

the contents of **package.json** as well as **nuxt.config.js** and **Procfile** are in the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/nissow/6494c2521118d1e7a7c00260de5a0c36)

My `nuxt.config.js`

```js
import colors from "vuetify/es5/util/colors";
import i18n from "./i18n";

export default {
  mode: "spa",
  /*
   ** Headers of the page
   */
  head: {
    titleTemplate: "%s - " + process.env.npm_package_name,
    title: process.env.npm_package_name || "",
    meta: [
      { charset: "utf-8" },
      { name: "viewport", content: "width=device-width, initial-scale=1" },
      {
        hid: "description",
        name: "description",
        content: process.env.npm_package_description || "",
      },
    ],
    script: [{ src: "https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js" }],
    link: [
      { rel: "icon", type: "image/x-icon", href: "/favicon.ico" },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href: "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Monoton&display=swap",
      },
      {
        rel: "stylesheet",
        href:
          "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700|Material+Icons",
      },
    ],
  },

  server: {
    host: "0.0.0.0", // default: localhost
  },

  env: {
    BASE_URL: process.env.BASE_URL,
  },

  /*
   ** Customize the progress-bar color
   */
  loading: { color: "#fff" },
  /*
   ** Global CSS
   */
  css: [],
  /*
   ** Plugins to load before mounting the App
   */
  plugins: [
    { src: "~/plugins/vuex-persist", ssr: false },
    "~/plugins/filters.js",
    "~/plugins/vue-youtube.js",
    "~/plugins/vue-shortkey.js",
    "~/plugins/services.ts",
    "~/plugins/color.ts",
    "~/plugins/role.ts",
  ],
  /*
   ** Nuxt.js modules
   */
  modules: [
    ["nuxt-i18n", i18n],
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify",
    // Doc: https://axios.nuxtjs.org/usage
    "@nuxtjs/axios",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module",
  ],

  buildModules: [
    "@nuxt/typescript-build",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api/module",
    [
      "@nuxtjs/google-analytics",
      {
        id: process.env.GOOGLE_TRACKING_ID,
      },
    ],
  ],
  /*
   ** Axios module configuration
   ** See https://axios.nuxtjs.org/options
   */
  axios: {
    proxy: false,
  },

  /*
   ** vuetify module configuration
   ** https://github.com/nuxt-community/vuetify-module
   */
  vuetify: {
    theme: {
      primary: colors.blue.darken2,
      accent: colors.grey.darken3,
      secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
      info: colors.teal.lighten1,
      warning: colors.amber.base,
      error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
      success: colors.green.accent3,
      themes: {
        dark: {
          primary: "#21CFF3",
          accent: "#FF4081",
          secondary: "#ffe18d",
          success: "#4CAF50",
          info: "#2196F3",
          warning: "#FB8C00",
          error: "#FF5252",
        },
        light: {
          primary: "#1976D2",
          accent: "#e91e63",
          secondary: "#30b1dc",
          success: "#4CAF50",
          info: "#2196F3",
          warning: "#FB8C00",
          error: "#FF5252",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  /*
   ** Build configuration
   */
  build: {
    /*
     ** You can extend webpack config here
     */
    publicPath: process.env.PUBLIC_PATH || "/_nuxt/",
    extend(config, ctx) {
      // config.module.rules.push({
      //   test: /\.(txt|csv|conll|jsonl)$/i,
      //   loader: 'file-loader',
      //   options: {
      //     name: '[path][name].[ext]'
      //   }
      // })
      config.module.rules.push({
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.(txt|csv|json|jsonl)$/,
        loader: "raw-loader",
        exclude: /(node_modules)/,
      });
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(ogg|mp3|wav|mpe?g)$/i,
        loader: "file-loader",
        options: {
          name: "[path][name].[ext]",
        },
      });
    },
  },
};
```

My `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "doccano",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "doccano is an open source annotation tools for machine learning practitioner.",
  "author": "Hironsan",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts,.js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lintfix": "eslint --fix --ext .ts,.js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "precommit": "yarn lint",
    "test": "jest",
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.12.0",
    "@nuxtjs/composition-api": "^0.23.4",
    "@nuxtjs/proxy": "^2.0.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.2",
    "@toast-ui/vue-editor": "^1.1.1",
    "@vuejs-community/vue-filter-date-format": "^1.6.3",
    "@vuejs-community/vue-filter-date-parse": "^1.1.6",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.3",
    "codemirror": "^5.55.0",
    "filepond": "^4.26.1",
    "filepond-plugin-file-validate-type": "^1.2.6",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "nuxt": "^2.11.0",
    "nuxt-i18n": "^6.13.12",
    "papaparse": "^5.2.0",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.7",
    "tui-editor": "^1.4.10",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-filepond": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-shortkey": "^3.1.7",
    "vue-youtube": "^1.4.0",
    "vuetify": "^2.3.4",
    "vuex-persist": "^3.1.3",
    "wavesurfer.js": "^5.0.1",
    "yarn": "^1.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.14.12",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.0.4",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^3.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^5.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-analytics": "^2.3.0",
    "@nuxtjs/google-fonts": "^1.3.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.168",
    "@types/wavesurfer.js": "^5.0.1",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.18.1",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.19.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-standard": ">=14.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": ">=2.22.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": ">=23.18.0",
    "eslint-plugin-node": ">=11.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^1.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": ">=4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-standard": ">=4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "stylus": "^0.54.7",
    "stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.6"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your `nuxt.config.js` file and also say which commands do you run when it works locally, and those that you use for production?

Comment: @kissu  the commands i run locally are as follows  : 
`yarn install` to install dependencies which outputs unmet peer dependencies
`yarn build`  which represents `nuxt build` to build my nuxt app
`yarn start` which represents  `nuxt start` to run my application after build

Comment: Do you need a server or is static fine?

Comment: i have compiled it in SPA mode

Comment: This mode doesn't exist anymore. You need to have a `target`and `ssr` combo. So for SPA, you need to have `ssr: true` but you can choose either `'static'` or `'server'` depending on where you do want to host it. Do you need a server or is static fine?

Comment: i have a django rest framework backend with a mongodb database which i hosted in heroku, so i think i'll need a server i guess

Comment: Your backend and frontend stack has nothing to do actually. You don't **need** to host both in the same place neither btw.

Comment: i made it work i added a heroku post install script to my package.json and added some config vars to my heroku application thank you for the tips

Comment: Hi, did my answer helped somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure the `devDependencies` are being installed:
You have `"@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.0.4",` as a dev dependency...

Make sure your have this config value set:
`NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`
so that the devDependencies get installed!
You can do that online in the app settings "Config Vars" section,
or with Heroki cli:
`heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false`

Answer (score 0):

It was because of missing Vue module declaration, create vue-shim.d.ts file in the root directory and add the below content inside it

```js
declare module '*.vue' {
  import Vue from 'vue'
  export default Vue
}
```

Reference documentation: https://typescript.nuxtjs.org/guide/setup.html

And as mentioned here: https://github.com/nuxt/typescript/issues/153#issuecomment-543010838

Comment: the file you mentionned is already included in my project with proper configuration

Answer (score 0):

`mode` is obsolete as you can see here: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/configuration-glossary/configuration-mode#the-mode-property

I don't even know why I asked if you wanted a `target: 'server'` here since it's not even logic.
Since you want to have **an SPA only** (not the most beneficial with Nuxt tho), you should set the following in your `nuxt.config.js` file

```
ssr: false,
target: 'static',
```

Then, you can `yarn generate` and `yarn start` to double check that everything works locally. If it does, you can upload your generated `dist` directory on https://app.netlify.com/drop for debugging purposes.

If it works there (it should), you can then just plug some CI with a few clicks and it will enable you to simply push to your github repo for a new project generation!

Comment: thank you for the tips again, i'll refactor my code accordingly thank you again